# How to find an element without a data attribute in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='foo'></div>
<div class='foo' data-id='123'></div>
```

or

```
<div class='foo' data-id='123'></div>
<div class='foo'></div>
```

How to use jQuery to find the first div without the data-id?

Comment: I mean finding the element that does not have a value for `data-id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
$(".foo:not([data-id])")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#container').each(function(){
    if(this.hasAttr('data-id'))
    {
        //dosometing
    }
    else
    {
        //dosomething else
    }
});
```